# Vector of parametric objects

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a vector of objects of a parametric type, where each object has a different specialized type. Example:

```
template<typename A>
struct BaseAtom
{
    A _a;
};

struct AtomA : BaseAtom<int>
{};

int main()
{
    std::vector<BaseAtom*> v; // (1)

    AtomA a;

    v.push_back(&a);
}
```

and logically, this doesn't work because BaseAtom is a template type, and the template argument isn't specified in (1). How can I create a vector with this characteristics?

Answer (score 4):

You could derive `BaseAtom<A>` from a common non-templated class, and store pointers to that class:

```
struct Base {};

template<typename A>
struct BaseAtom: Base
{
    A _a;
};

struct AtomA : BaseAtom<int>
{};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Base*> v; // (1)

    AtomA a;

    v.push_back(&a);
}
```

Comment: commonly (or not so commonly) known as external polymorphism.

Comment: But then, this vector could contain objects derived from Base but not from BaseAtom.

Comment: @Peregring-lk: Not if `BaseAtom<A>` are the only things to derive from `Base` (which is what I had in mind).

Comment: If `Base` has a pure virtual interface (functionality it _must_ support), why is that a problem?

Comment: The classes need to share the same base class. You could also use std::vector<Base<int>*>, which would cover your example but it's probably not what you want.  If you need more flexibility you can use boost::any: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/any.html

Answer (score 2):

Either choose some specialisation of the template to put in the vector:

```
std::vector<BaseAtom<int>*> v;
```

or define a non-template base class:

```
struct BaseAtomBase {};  // put anything independent of the template parameter here

template <typaname A>
struct BaseAtom : BaseAtomBase
{
    A _a;
};

std::vector<BaseAtomBase*> v;
```

but note that this doesn't allow you to access the templated parts of the objects from the vector.

You'll need to figure out which of these (if either) is suitable for the problem you're trying to solve.